# Issue outputting data generated from a user-defined function that uses sapply()

Tags: r, dataframe, montecarlo

I am attempting to summarize the data generated from looping through data using sapply() and am not sure why I can't access the dataframe that's generated.  I'm setting up a monte-carlo simulation, and I have a function that sets up parameters and an estimate, and I wish to apply that function a set number of times per datapoint in a data set.  So, I am using replicate() for my function, for which I have within a function that uses sapply().  It appears to work, however the data cannot be accessed in order to describe the resulting distributions of estimates; the data frame is not output, but is printed.  Nice, but I need to now take them and calculate means and confidence intervals, and probably plot some.

Here is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
repapply <- function(iter, datapoint){
  estimates <- sapply(datapoint, function(datapoint){
    replicate(n=iter, expr=generate_data(datapoint))
  })
  estimatesdf <- data.frame(estimates)
  return(estimatesdf)
}
#test:
repapply(1000, measure)
```

Could anyone explain why there isn't any output dataframe?  It prints the information below:

```
X1                                                   X2
1 476.454335, 6.240725, 4.433396, 24.017384, 36.900104 594.890067, 2.310075, 7.210158, 21.379092, 30.256849
X3                                                   X4
1 359.167706, 5.817891, 7.276368, 20.776742, 23.539489 459.848602, 3.826445, 4.319803, 23.774576, 52.130509
X5                                                   X6
1 504.624220, 8.159456, 4.110860, 23.805009, 42.983076 578.252014, 6.749054, 5.880862, 23.312351, 42.320465
X7                                                   X8
1 427.196750, 7.458934, 3.295953, 24.764725, 45.647360 284.724297, 5.234101, 6.481678, 20.159478, 42.160186
X9                                                  X10
1 307.605356, 4.386591, 5.562230, 22.711697, 3.675961 418.109465, 5.618156, 3.135784, 24.503502, 34.891379
 ...
```

Comment: What is a "measure" and what does "generate_data" function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

You have to assign `repapply(1000, measure)` to a value/object. In other words, you have to name it. For instance:

`df <- repapply(1000, measure)`

#### Why:

When you define objects in a function environment, they are local to that function's scope. So, when you return `estimatesdf`, you are really just returning the literal data.frame that it points to. Hence, you could even compress the last two lines of your function into `return(data.frame(estimates))`, and you would get the same result.

---

#### Alternatively:

Unlike objects defined in a function, pre-existing (outside the scope of the function) objects which are *modified* in a function do retain their value outside of the function's scope. If you define `estimatesdf` (e.g., by setting it equal to 0) outside the function, and eliminated the `return()` call, then running `repapply(1000, measure)` would set the `estimatesdf` to the desired data.frame.

Comment: Ah, yes that works. I knew it would be something simple.  Super helpful!  Vielen Dank, thanks very much, and cheers.